# How to echo php code and use it?

Tags: php

```
<?php echo $row["html"]; ?>
```

Inside of the $row["html"] there's:

```
<?php $Site->Nav($owner); ?>
```

but when I echo it, it only echoes:

```
Nav($owner); ?>
```

How may I print the full and make it usable, which means that it will print the function Nav?

I've tried to replace `<?php` with [[// i the database, and just before echoing it, I change back with replace. But without success

Comment: You would use `eval()` for this but this typically is a bad code smell and means you could be doing this a better way.

Comment: You want to display code on web page or want to execute it and then display the output on web page?

Comment: I want it to execute and see the output, not the code

Comment: if you want to see the content of $row["html"], you have to use `html_entities`. if you want to *execute* it, you have to rethink your whole software architecture because you should not *ever* do that unless you know exactly and in every little detail what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function of php. See the example below.

```
$string = 'cup';
$name = 'coffee';
$str = 'This is a $string with my $name in it.';
echo $str. "\n";
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
```

Might be it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval` function. It might solve your problem like this:

```
<?php echo eval($row["html"]); ?>
```

Keep the code as is in DB as if you are writing it in PHP file but without PHP opening and closing tags i.e. `<?php` and `?>`. I haven't checked this (as i am not sure what `$Site->Nav($owner);` will do) but hope it would work in this case.

Comment: Note that you should keep the value of `$row["html"]` to `$Site->Nav($owner);`

Comment: What is the value of `$row['html']` currently you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are wanting to output the results of `$Site->Nav($owner);`

I have no idea what this is expected to output, but assuming it is a string of some kind that you wish to display (hence echo) - an example of achieving this would be calling your code and have that method return the value, so you can echo it out. Ie:

```
function Nav($owner){

  // Do your stuff

  return 'Your Desired Output';
}
```

Then on your page you would have

```
<?php echo $Site->Nav($owner); ?>
```

Which would echo "Your Desired Output".